# Windows sockets htons(80) vs 0x5000

Tags: sockets, network-programming, port, htonl

When I am writing port to SOCKADDR_IN structure, can I use 0x5000 instead of htons(80)?

(Why 0x5000? -- I debugged htons(80) and it returned 0x5000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but it won't be portable. `htons` exists for you not to worry about byte ordering in your computer and network (and they can be different on various systems).

Answer (score 0):

You can, but why would you want to? What's the problem with being portable? and clear? and the same as everyone else who has ever written this code?